# How to combine google recaptcha and login in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, asp.net-identity, captcha

In our ASP MVC site, a login form for members currently exists. I am trying to add Captcha to reduce bot attacks *(my login is not simple membership, but something similar, however the concept remains the same)*. I understand how the login request works and its making a round trip to my server.

**How does a recaptcha work in tandem with a membership login-in site**. *I understand the SPAM side of it*, but how to work it in tandem with user authentication/authorization during login. So, do I pass on to the authenticate only after captcha passes, or what checks and steps do I follow? A picture and sample would help...

- If I was to *implement recaptcha in tandem with membership*, What are the sequence of
  steps that are happening *or should happen*, so that I can model the
  code?

Comment: NuGet **Google reCAPTCHA V2** for MVC 4 and 5

- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reCAPTCH.MVC/)
- [Demo And Document](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usually steps for a *captcha* are like below

1. Generate captcha (`image` + `key`)
2. Store the `key` in `Session`.
3. Send `image` to user
4. Receive response from user with the `key` that user interpret from image
5. Verify if *original key* from `Session` match *user key* from `input`.
6. Take a decision, `if` valid do the register/login `else` captcha invalid, repeat with step 1

**Notes:**

1. Usually this steps are done `async` and they are in group of 3. Steps *1,2,3* are for **providing** the captcha. Steps *4,5,6* are for **verify** the captcha.
2. You notice, the steps are nothing to do with *simple membership* or any others. The capcha is used to **validate a sensitive request** like *payments* not only *log in* or *register* and to prove that you are **human**.